# Retornar uma classe no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho esses campos hidden no meu cshtml:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="txtGeoTo" name="txtGeoTo" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtDateStart" name="txtDateStart" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtDateEnd" name="txtDateEnd" />
```

Propriedades:

```c-sharp
public string txtOrigem { get; set; }
public string datIda { get; set; }
public string datVolta { get; set; }
```

Como eu faço para essa classe direta no meu jquery

```javascript
function PegaHotelPacote() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Passo/PegaHotelPacote',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ aqui entra minha classe, acho}),
        sucess: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi a questão. Por favor releia a questão, pois não está claro.

Comment: Serializei assim e vou testar. Entendi errado a questão.
resultado = jQuery.parseJSON('{"txtDestino": "' + $("#txtGeoTo").val() + '" , "datIda": "' + $("#txtDateStart").val() +
                                 '", "datVolta": "' + $("#txtDateEnd").val() + '", "intAdultos": "' + $("#txtAdulto").val() + '" }');

    $.ajax({
         
        url: '/Passo/PegaHotelPacote',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({_hotel: resultado}),
        sucess: function (data) {

        },

Comment: Você poderia editar a questão com as novas informações, assim, como comentário fica muito confuso.

Answer (score 1):

**Opção 1:**

Você pode usar o próprio método [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    ...
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="txtGeoTo" name="txtGeoTo" />
    <input type="hidden" id="txtDateStart" name="txtDateStart" />
    <input type="hidden" id="txtDateEnd" name="txtDateEnd" />
</form>
```

**Opção 2:**

Passando um objeto como parâmetro:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {
           txtOrigem : $('#txtGeoTo').val(),
           datIda: $('#txtDateStart').val(),
           datVolta: $('#txtDateEnd').val()
    },
    ...
});
```

---

Em ambos os casos você só precisa fazer isso, o .Net se encarrega de mapear para a model/viewmodel passada como parâmetro na Action.

Answer (score 0):

**Solução**

**Crie um classe Modelo**

```
public class Modelo
{
     public string txtOrigem { get; set; }
     public DateTime datIda { get; set; }
     public DateTime datVolta { get; set; }
}
```

**Crie o seu Controle**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ModelosController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostModelo(MvcApplication1.Models.Modelo modelo)
        {
            return Json(modelo, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Crie uma View a partir do controle assim:**

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {            
            $("#ButEnviar").click(function () {    
                var dados = "txtOrigem=" + $("#txtGeoTo").val()
                dados = dados + "&datIda=" + $("#txtDateStart").val();
                dados = dados + "&datVolta=" + $("#txtDateEnd").val();                
                $.post("/Modelos/PostModelo", dados, function (data) {
                    alert(data.txtOrigem + "\n" + data.datIda + "\n" + data.datVolta)
                }, 'json');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>        
        <input type="hidden" id="txtGeoTo" name="txtGeoTo" value="Origem 1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="txtDateStart" name="txtDateStart" value="10/10/2010" />
        <input type="hidden" id="txtDateEnd" name="txtDateEnd" value="12/10/2010" />
        <button type="button" id="ButEnviar">Enviar</button>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quanto clicar no Enviar ele vai executar o [Jquery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), que está em `$("#ButEnviar")` evento `click`, ele vai buscar as informações nos campos do tipo `hidden`, e enviar via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) para o método do controller (`/Modelos/PostModelo`), como demostrado na figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o processamento do método ele reenvia novamente os mesmo dados para View

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, você pode utilizar da melhor maneira possível.

Obs: eu coloquei os `datIda` e `datVolta` como [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)